# Modeling database records as types

Tags: f#

I'm rewriting a C# library in F# in which most of the classes map one-to-one with database tables (similar to ActiveRecord).  I'm considering whether to use records or classes (maybe even DUs?).  There's a fair amount of validation in the property setters to maintain invariants.  **What would be the best way to model this in F#?**  I don't want an object that violates business logic to be persisted to the database.  Any ideas are welcome.

A few additional thoughts...
Is it better to move the invariants to an external 'controller' class? Coming from C# it feels wrong to allow an object that corresponds to a database record to contain anything that can't be saved to the database.  I suppose because failing earlier seems better than failing later.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a more 'functional' (or simply different) approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can have your data in a record, and still keep the validation logic with the data type, by attaching methods to the record:

```
type Person =
    { First : string;
      Last  : string; } with
    member x.IsValid () =
        let hasValue = System.String.IsNullOrEmpty >> not    
        hasValue x.First && hasValue x.Last

let jeff = { First = "Jeff"; Last = "Goldblum" }
let jerry = { jeff with First = "Jerry" }
let broken = { jerry with Last = "" }

let valid = [jeff; jerry; broken] 
            |> List.filter (fun x -> x.IsValid())
```

The copy semantics for records are almost as convenient as setting a property. The validation doesn't happen on property set, but it's easy to filter a list of records down to only the valid ones.

Comment: This approach feels very natural in F#, but I have a hard time ditching the cleanliness of fully encapsulated classes. Maybe there's not a best-of-both-worlds solution. I'm just exploring the options.

Comment: You really should stick with the nice encapsulated objects.

Answer (score 2):

This should actually be a good way for you to handle it. Having your validation logic in the constructor will give you piece of mind later on in your code because the object is immutable. This also opens up multi-threading possibilities.

**Immutable Version**

```
type Customer (id, name) =

    do // Constructor
        if id <= 0 then 
            raise(new ArgumentException("Invalid ID.", "id"))
        elif String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) then 
            raise(new ArgumentException("Invalid Name.", "name"))    

    member this.ID
        with get() = id
    member this.Name
        with get() = name

    member this.ModifyName value =
        new Customer(id, value)
```

**Mutable Version**

```
type Customer (id) =

    let mutable name = ""

    do // Constructor
        if id <= 0 then 
            raise(new ArgumentException("Invalid ID.", "id"))

    member this.ID
        with get() = id
    member this.Name
        with get() = name  
        and set value =
            if String.IsNullOrEmpty(name) then 
                raise(new ArgumentException("Invalid Name.", "value")) 
            name <- value
```

Comment: Most operations on these types are of the form: load, modify, save. Short of having copy semantics (like records) for classes, it seems that requires the type being mutable and having the validation logic in the property setters.

Comment: So basically copy what I have in C#?

Comment: Yeah you don't really want to separate the validation from the object.

Comment: I thought there might be an approach that provides some additional benefits of functional programming. For instance, records feature immutability and easy copying and construction...but I just can't control what goes into them!

Comment: My first example will be the most useful with regards functional programming. The only constraint is that if you want to change the object you need to create a new instance. It is really a matter of how you want the object to interact with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at my FunctionalNHibernate project? It's designed as a layer on top of nhibernate to let you declaratively map records to a database. It's early days, but it's just about usable:
http://bitbucket.org/robertpi/functionalnhibernate/

Comment: I have actually. I joined the Google Group and have been keeping an eye on the progress. But since I don't have any experience with NHibernate, and I already have an ORM I've written in C# (which I'm in  the process of converting), I've been reluctant to make a wholesale switch to another ORM.

Comment: Also, I'm wondering since NHibernate was written for C#, will an F# version exploit any of the benefits of functional programming? I'd like to see an ORM designed ground-up from a functional perspective...which hopefully would close the RDBMS/functional programming impedance mismatch as much as possible.

Comment: A rewrite from the ground up would be ideal, but from my perspective NHibernate already provides some nice features for abstracting the RDBMS your using which I think would be very time consuming to rewrite from scratch. Or put another way, I don't think you'll be able to use all of NH, but you'll be able to use enough there to make it worth it.